# Parse String timestamp to Instant throws Unsupported field: InstantSeconds

Tags: java, parsing, timestamp, java-8

I am trying to convert a String into an Instant. Can you help me out?

I get following exception:

> Caused by: java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: InstantSeconds
>       at java.time.format.Parsed.getLong(Parsed.java:203)
>       at java.time.Instant.from(Instant.java:373)

My code looks basically like this

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String timestamp = "2016-02-16 11:00:02";
TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = formatter.parse(timestamp);
Instant result = Instant.from(temporalAccessor);
```

I am using Java 8 Update 72.

Comment: Your first input is not an instant. The timezone is missing.

Comment: I get this error trying to use DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime 2-arg constructor, of which I can find 0 examples on the internet.   It doesn't like FormatStyle.SHORT passed as the timeFormat 2nd parameter to the method.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

A simpler method is to add the default timezone to the formatter object when declaring it

```
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
                                    .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                                    .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
Instant result = Instant.from(formatter.parse(timestamp));
```

Comment: I like how compact this solution is.

Comment: I still got this error until I noticed that I used `hh` instead of `HH` by accident.

Answer (score 50):

Here is how to get an Instant with a default time zone. Your String can not be parsed straight to Instant because timezone is missing. So you can always get the default one

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

String timestamp = "2016-02-16 11:00:02";
TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = formatter.parse(timestamp);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.from(temporalAccessor);
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.systemDefault());
Instant result = Instant.from(zonedDateTime);
```

Comment: BTW, I recently had a requirement to parse a String to Date without knowing exact format in advance, essentially try to parse any string that represents a valid date. So I wrote an article about how I solved this problem. Here is the link: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/java-8-javatime-package-parsing-any-string-date-michael-gantman?trk=pulse_spock-articles

Answer (score 0):

I wrote such simple function to perform the conversion:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.sql.Timestamp;


public class SqlTimestampParser {

public static Timestamp parseTimestamp(String dateTime, String format) throws Exception {
    if (format == null || format.trim().length() == 0) {
        throw new Exception("No format defined!");
    }
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format);
    ZonedDateTime timed = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTime, formatter);
    timed.format(formatter);
    Instant x = Instant.from(timed);
    return Timestamp.from(x);
}
}
```

With sample usage:

```
SqlTimestampParser.parseTimestamp('2020-09-17 16:20:35.294000+00:00',"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX")
```

Answer (score -4):

First convert your date into util date using date format as you don't have time zone in your input. Then you can convert that date into Instant date. This will give you date with accurate time.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String timestamp = "2016-02-16 11:00:02";
Date xmlDate = dateFormat.parse(timestamp);
dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
Instant instantXmlDate = Instant.parse(dateFormat.format(xmlDate));
```

Comment: Don't propose legacy apis that are inherently unsafe if there are clearly better alternatives presented already.