# How to choose correct date type for spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, zoneddatetime, localdatetime

I need to implement endpoint like that:

```
@GetMapping("/localdatetime")
public SomeObhject dateTime(@RequestParam("localDateTime") LocalDateTime date) {
```

By date it should query smth from database and return to the client.

My question is which date type should I use ?

- LocalDateTime
- ZonedDatetime
- OffsetDateTime

?

Something else ?

Which advantages and disadvantage ?

AFAIK the best way to pass date - is pass it in the UTC format but it doesn't answer my question directly.

Comment: It depends - if the timezone is relevant, use ZonedDateTime. If not, LocalDateTime is usually the best fit.

Comment: @1615903 could you pease explain phrase  **if the timezone is relevant** ? Client and server might be in different time zones

Comment: In this case: _"By date it should query smth from database"_  - it's the _something_ in your database that determines if timezone is relevant or not. See @MichaelGantman 's answer for a good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

LocalDateTime does not keep the time zone info, and thus could not be converted to an exact moment in time without providing additional info - time zone. OffsetDateTime and ZonedDatetime both hold the time zone info, ZonedDatetime holds a bit more info, read about it in the Javadoc. If your application does not need to take into account timezone (for instance it is an app for localized use and all the times assumed to be always in local time zone), then working with LocalDateTime is simpler than the others plus others will hold some redundant info. But if you do need to take into account the timezone then you need one of the two that hold this info. I personally prefer to work with ZonedDatetime if I need to take time zone into account

Comment: Is it correct to say that if we pass date as UTC timestamp we could use any: 
LocalDateTime, ZonedDateTime or OffsetDateTime ?

Comment: Actually I don't need exact client time zone but I need to know the moment

Comment: No, if you want your time to be in UTC - which is a time zone you can not use LocalDateTime. You will have to use either ZonedDateTime or OffsetDateTime, as you do take timezone in consideration

Comment: I mean that client is responsible into convertation into UTC timezone. And server expects that is  passed as a UTC. Do you mean that Spring controller will consider passed date as a his local date ?

Comment: No, if you use LocalDateTime then server will not know and will not care about time zone.  What you are saying is that you want to make an assumption that all the times are in UTC but you don't want to keep that info. So, when you would want to convert your LocalDateTime into moment in time you will have to tell that your time should be considered as UTC. See the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35610597/parse-string-timestamp-to-instant-throws-unsupported-field-instantseconds/35611452#35611452

Comment: I just checked with my colleague. I was in UTC time zone, and he was in +3 time zone. He passed 20:35 and I was in debug in controller and I receive 20:35

Comment: If you used LocalDateTime, that would be the case. but that is not probably what you want. Because your colleague sent you the time in GMT+3, so if you want all your times in UTC you would need to get 17:35 (20:35 - 3hours). The point is, you need to be clear on what is your requirements, and based on that choose the appropriate data type

Comment: So if we consider that all datetime in UTC we can use LocalDateTime

Comment: This means that you rely on the client to do the conversion, which I would strongly discourage if I was the architect of your project. But if you willing to go with that, than, yes I suppose you could. I personally would strongly recommend not to rely on client and use ZonedDateTime. And if you wish you could convert all your times to UTC or keep them as they were as either way they represent exact pint in time